# Integer template parameter for data size in class

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a class calculating various metrics over an array of values. Initially, I had the list of the values initialized dynamically

```
class Foo
{
    int nStats;
    double * stats;
    Foo(int nStats);
    ~Foo();

    double F1();
    double F2();
    // ...
}
```

with the constructor simply initializing `stats = new double[nStats];`. However, for various reasons, I now need to have a fixed-size versions of the same class as well. The best way to achieve this seems by templating by size, in the style of `std::array<>`

```
template<int nStats>
class FooFixed
{
    double stats[nStats];

    double F1();
    double F2();
    // ...
}
```

I understand that even though the code for class functions F1, F2 ... is similar across all values of nStats, the nature of templates prevents me from defining them in source files, even in c++11. However, is there a trick which will allow me to code those functions only once, instead of copy-pasting them twice, first for initial `class Foo` and then for new templated `class FooFixed<int>`? As an example, summation function will clearly stay the same for both classes and I would hate to just copy-paste it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of static polymorphism mechanism:

```
template <class T>
struct FooParent {
   double *get_stats() {
      return static_cast<T*>(this)->stats;
   }
   int get_n() {
      return static_cast<T*>(this)->n;
   }
   // all your implementation using get_stats()[K] instead of stats[K]
};

struct Foo: FooParent<Foo> {
   int n;
   double * stats;
};

template <int nStats>
struct FooFixed: FooParent<FooFixed<nStats>> {
    int n = nStats;
    double stats[nStats];
};
```

Comment: Neat. Is the compile output the same for `FooFixed: FooParent<FooFixed<nStats>>` as for plain old `FooFixed<nStats>` ? I.e. is there any runtime overhead associated with this trick, or all the substitutions are made during compile-time?

Comment: @random There is no runtime overhead of this approach, it should get inlined

Answer (score 2):

You may have

```
template <typename Container>
class FooBase;

template <std::size_t N>
class FooBase<std::array<int, N>>
{
protected:
    FooBase() : m_data{} {}
    std::size_t get_size() const { return N; }
    int* get_data() { m_data.data();}
private:
    std::array<int, N> m_data;
};

template <>
class FooBase<std::vector<int>>
{
protected:
    explicit FooBase(std::size_t size) : m_data(size) {}
    std::size_t get_size() const { return m_data.size(); }
    int* get_data() { m_data.data();}
private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};
```

And then

```
template <typename Container>
class Foo_impl : protected FooBase<Container>
{
    using FooBase::Foobase;

    double F1();
    double F2();
    // ...
};
```

And finally:

```
template<std::size_t N>
using Foo = Foo_impl<std::vector<int>>;

template<std::size_t N>
using FooFixed = Foo_impl<std::array<int, N>>;
```

Comment: almost perfect. With a little more work it could be made to not require any explicit specialisation. A Templated varadiac constructor should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Standing on the shoulders of giants... refactoring Jared's code to eliminate the need for a specialisation, plus fixing some typos so it will compile gives us:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <class Container>
struct FooBase
{
    template<class...Args>
    FooBase(Args&&...args) : m_data { std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}

    using const_iterator = typename Container::value_type const *;

    const_iterator begin() const {
        return std::addressof(*std::begin(m_data));
    }

    const_iterator end() const {
        return std::next(begin(), m_data.size());
    }

protected:
    int* get_data() { m_data.data();}


private:
    Container m_data;
};

template <typename Container>
class Foo_impl : public FooBase<Container>
{
public:
    using FooBase<Container>::FooBase;


    double F1();
    double F2();
    // ...
};

using Foo = Foo_impl<std::vector<int>>;

template<std::size_t N>
using FooFixed = Foo_impl<std::array<int, N>>;

int main()
{

    auto fbv = Foo { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto fba = FooFixed<5> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    auto fbv2 = Foo { std::begin(fba), std::end(fba) };


    return 0;
}
```